# Where did it go wrong in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed
        self.hp
def Berserker(self):
    self.speed == 12
    self.hp == 6

print("Berserkers stats are: " + Berserker())
```

So, What have I done wrong? As you can see, I'm very new to Python.
The error I'm getting is: TypeError: Berserker() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Your `__init__` doesn't do anything. It will also throw an `AttributeError` when you try to instantiate your class. You should start with a basic Python tutorial, and then move on to OOP.

Comment: And your `Berserker` method is not indented properly in to your class, so it is not being treated like an instance method, but a function.

Comment: Did you mean for a berserker to be a subclass or an instance of a person? Because that's not at all what you've written.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you're missing various things. Additionally, this is considered a "bad question" on SO; we sort of prefer specific questions about how to use a language or technology, as opposed to "What is wrong in this code?" (which is what your question is). However, I think it's more important for you to learn Python than how to form a "good" SO question, so I've provided an answer. In the future, it'd be appreciated if you do a little more research and show where you've previously looked for help before posting a question like this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quite a few things, but I'll help you out!

Your `__init__` function doesn't do anything. Let's give it some base stats. I'll say that a `Player`'s default speed and health will be 10 and 100, respectively. Then we'll make `Berserker` a *subclass* of `Player` (I think that's what you were going for?). And lastly, I'll give `Player` a method that will allow you to get a string-formatted output for its values.

First, the new `Player`:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, speed=10, health=100):
        self.speed = speed
        self.health = health

    def __str__(self):
        return "A player with speed {} and health {}.".format(self.speed, self.health)
```

And now for the `Berserker`. I'll give it a base speed of 15 and health of 85. (Obviously the specifics are up to you!)

```
class Berserker(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(speed=15, health=85)
```

Lastly, we can create these and print the value. I'll make a couple different versions so you can see how it works. (And I'll use the regular Python interpreter for this).

```
>>> p1 = Player()
>>> p2 = Player(7, 120)
>>> b = Berserker()
>>> print(p1)
A player with speed 10 and health 100.
>>> print(p2)
A player with speed 7 and health 120.
>>> print(b)
A player with speed 15 and health 85.
```

Hopefully this gives you a good place to start!

Answer (score 1):

You did a bunch of mistakes there  :

- Indent your Berserker method to be part of the class
- Assignement in python is with one "=" not with "==" ( like most programming languages actually )
- Give speed and hp initial values or don't put them in the constructor at all , in python variables are created when they're assigned a value.
- Make your Berserker method return a string to be able to print it
- Create an instance of your class

a working version of you code should be like this :

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.hp = 0
    def Berserker(self):
        self.speed = 12
        self.hp = 6
        return "speed {} hp  {}".format(self.speed,self.hp) 
m = Player()
print("Berserkers stats are: " + m.Berserker())
```

Now that's a working version but it's still poorly designed IMO ,this is better :

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.hp = 0
    def Berserker(self):
        self.speed = 12
        self.hp = 6
    def __str__(self):
        return "speed {} hp  {}".format(self.speed,self.hp) 
m = Player()
m.Berserker()
print(m)
```